# Extract data from a text

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have this text :

```
BEGIN_GENERAL 8
LastLine 20130801000028 136606 57288915 25883895742573
FirstTime 20130701130426
LastTime 20130731235941
LastUpdate 20130802015823 1 0 0 0 0
TotalVisits 360
TotalUnique 246
MonthHostsKnown 0
MonthHostsUnknown 454
END_GENERAL
```

I want to extract `TotalVisits` & `TotalUnique` so I try:

```
preg_match('/^TotalVisits ([0-9]{4}) /ms', $awstats, $matches);
$data= $matches;
print_array($data);
```

It render me an empty array! why is that ? Thanks

Comment: In your example, TotalVisits has only 3 digits ("360"), your RegEx expects exactly 4 digits ({4}), try "{1,4}"...

Comment: What do you think `{4}` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call like this:

```
preg_match('/TotalVisits\s([0-9]{3})/', $awstats, $matches);
```

Outputs:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'TotalVisits 360' (length=15)
  1 => string '360' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You ask for a 4-digit number while the provided one only has 3 digits. Try using this instead:

```
[0-9]+
```

If you want to specify a range (lets say values between 10 and 9999 should be valid) you could also do:

```
[0-9]{2,4}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your example doesn't work is that ([0-9]**{4}**) forces it to look for a number that is four digits long. Also, replacing [0-9] with \d shortens the expression a bit.

How about something like this:

```
^TotalVisits (\d+)$
```

It matches:

TotalVisits `360`

Same format will work for `TotalUnique`

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/gN9lL2).